# can't get the value of something in a dict with a key

Tags: python, dictionary, get

so i have this code

```
test = json.load(open('data.json'))
print (test)
print(test[MACadress])
```

and i can't get the value of MACadress, i already tried test.get(MACadress)

i get this error:

//this is test :

{'MACadress': '0x1c1bb5d3ce17', 'daate': '2020-03-19 17:33:19.715129', 'CPU': 2051.929375, 'mem': 26.0, 'disk': 57.1, 'process': 333, 'users': '1'}

//error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recepteur_infos_machines.py", line 11, in 
    print(test[MACadress])
NameError: name 'MACadress' is not defined

Comment: You need to quote `'MACadress'`

Comment: `json.load` will return a dict-like python object. To get the value you need to use it the same way as you would any dict. So try `test['MACadress']` - notice the quotes around the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(test["MACadress"])` the key is a string. Without quotes you are referencing a non-existent variable.

Comment: thank you ! 
but now i can't insert my data in my table i get this error :


sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 7, and there are 14 supplied.


i mean i can't see why it says i am supplying 14 bindings


c.executemany('INSERT INTO infos (MACadress, daate, CPU, mem, disk, process, users) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(test.get("MACadress"),test.get("daate"),test.get("CPU"),test.get("mem"),test.get("disk"),test.get("process"),test.get("users")))

maybe it counts the 7 "?"  + what i submit ?

Comment: Ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround MACadress with hyphens, for python to treat it as a string. 
That is, the code should be:

test = json.load(open('data.json'))

print (test)

print(test['MACadress'])

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary key in this case is a string. (A word without quotations is a variable in python)

So if you write the following:

`print(test['MACadress'])`

It should print out the string:  '0x1c1bb5d3ce17'